# Can't reboot system

Tags: reboot

I'm using the latest stable release of Kubuntu. I'm dual booting it off a SSD with Win10. It's mostly a fresh install, all I've done is tinker with the desktop.

Everything works fine, except when I got to reboot. I do this by using the desktop environment, and click on reboot. When I reboot, my screen goes black, the OS system seems to turn off but the hardware is still running. No amount of time will allow it to reboot, it gets stuck. I have to manually turn it off and on again. I have no problems with rebooting in some other Linux distros I tried.

Not sure how to approach this. Any help is appreciated!